# Первый список - это набор индексов ко второму списку, с которого необходимо записать значения под этими индексами в третий список. Как это сделать?

Tags: python, list

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой задачей на одном из форумов:

Есть список b_index:

```
b_index= [1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
```

И есть список b:

```
b = [10.0, 0.0, 15.0, -30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0]
```

Список b_index является набором индексов (порядковых номеров) к значениям списка b начиная с 1, а не с 0 (учитывайте это, ведь порядковый отсчёт в Python ведётся с 0). Вывести в отдельный список results значения списка b, которые соответствуют индексам, заданным в списке b_index.

Т.е. в списке results должны быть значения:

```
results = [10.0, 0.0, -30.0, 0.0, 18.0]
```

Как это сделать? Пробовал со вложенными циклами но результат не совпадал. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, ваши попытки решения. В смысле код, который вы пытались написать.

Comment: А в чем загвоздка? Обращаться к списку по индексу умеешь? Это в принципе все, что тут нужно знать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего сложного:

```
b_index = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
b = [10.0, 0.0, 15.0, -30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.0] 
print([b[i - 1] for i in b_index])
```

Вывод:

```
[10.0, 0.0, -30.0, 0.0, 18.0]
```

Comment: Не лучшая практика - отвечать на учебный вопрос без попытки самостоятельного решения.